# Lumen middleware closure error

Tags: laravel, lumen

In Lumen 5.5, I have modified the example middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Client;

class CheckHeaders
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    ...

    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In bootstrap/app, I've added

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
'client' => App\Http\Middleware\CheckHeaders::class,
]);
```

And attached the middleware to the route:

```
$router->get('api/tokens', ['middleware' => 'client'], 'TokensController@index');
```

When I try instead to use the facade

```
Route::get('api/tokens', 'TokensController@index')->middleware('client');
```

This time the error is `Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::middleware()`

I'm not sure if its different in Lumen as I've done this before, but now getting error

```
Undefined variable: closure
...
in RoutesRequests.php (line 286)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this in two param instead three

```
 $app->get('api/tokens', [
      'middleware' => 'client'
      'as' => 'tokens', 
      'uses' => 'TokensController@index'
  ]);
```

Comment: thank you - not sure why I couldn't find that format in the docs